# Silverstripe forbid editing of page but allow to create subpages

Tags: php, permissions, silverstripe

I have a NewsholderPage and NewsPage. NewsPages are subpages of NewsholderPage.
I need users of a certain group to be able to create NewsPages, but not to be able to edit the NewsholderPage.
If I put the following code into the NewsholderPage...

```
public function canEdit($member = null){
    if(permission::check('SUPERUSER')){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

... then a not-admin cannot edit the NewsholderPage but also gets a "forbidden" message, when he is trying to create a NewsPage as child of the NewsholderPage.
What is the best way to allow the creation of subpages, while not allowing to edit the parent page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to override the `canAddChildren` method on NewsholderPage to return something other than the default (which is simply `$this->canEdit()`). To get the default behaviour back, you can use something like:

```php
public function canAddChildren($member = null) {
  // Call SiteTree::canEdit rather than NewsholderPage::canEdit
  return parent::canEdit($member);
}
```